# How to prevent click function if certain child is clicked?

Tags: jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2pt8/)

For some reason, the `not()` in the `on()` function is not working. I only want the function to run if the aqua `section` (parent) element is clicked, and do nothing if the gray `div` (child) element is clicked.

jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<section><div class="someClass"></div><section>');

$('body').on('click', 'section:not(".someClass")', function(){
    alert('Aqua not gray clicked.');
});
```

Also, why does the alert pop up twice if the `section` aqua element is clicked?

Comment: The section doesn't have the class, the div does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the actual element that was clicked (`e.target`) has that class:

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('someClass')) return;
```

Comment: +1, but I'd go with `if ($(e.target).closest('.someClass')[0]) { return false; }` in case the `.someClass` div has children: http://jsfiddle.net/F2pt8/1/

Answer (score 1):

There would be space between section and `:not` for descendant selector and you probable need has with not, as the intended element is descendant of section. With space it will look sections not having class `someclass`.

```
$('body').on('click', 'section :not(:has(.someClass))', function(){
    alert('Aqua not gray clicked.');
});
```

You can bind event to section and by pass the execution of code in handler for section who have descendant with class someclass.

```
$('body').on('click', 'section', function(){
    if($(this).find('.someClass').length > 0) return;
    alert('Aqua not gray clicked.');
});
```

Comment: Sweet, that was easy and fast.

Comment: You need to explain why.  Also, this won't do what he wants.

Comment: *" I only want the function to run if the aqua section (parent) element is clicked,"*

Comment: I'd omit those quotes in the `:not()`.

Comment: I wouldn't use `:not` for this at all.